# Error Converting Nvarchar to Float ,all register where verified with isnumeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

```
select isnumeric(convert(varchar(20),replace(Replace(Price,'.',''),',','.'))),
Replace(price,',','.') 
from Products
order by price desc
```

My query says that all the registers are numeric but when i try to convert them to float ou decimal 
i get the error :

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 57
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

[the data from conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLapA.png)

Comment: Why on Earth are you storing a *price* as a `VARCHAR`?  `IsNumeric()` isn't perfect, by the way (`Select IsNumeric('.')` will return `1` for example) and shouldn't be used as a definite means of determining whether a `VARCHAR` can be converted to a numeric datatype.

Comment: im working in a database made by another person

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Depending on the version of sql server (2012 or later) you can use try_parse. IsNumeric is nearly useless for most types of numeric checks. Other values that pass IsNumeric are comma and dollar sign. Even things like 1e4 will return 1. It is basically a "can this value be converted into any datatype that is roughly a number" type of function.